# iPhone cron (task execution in specified time)

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, cron

Can we define a time or times on which the system automatically generates an event, shows e.g. notification dialog with button, which, when pressed, starts, the application? Something like cron on unix. I am looking for way to schedule jobs to be started either periodically or at certain times.

Regards,
STeN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're no doubt aware, there's no real background processing on the iPhone, but you can set `UILocalNotification` which pop up a dialog at some future point in time and can prompt the user to open your app. Of course, the user could press cancel and *not* launch your app.